# IF SYNTAX AND EXAMPLE in CRM ON DEMAND

Tags: iif, ondemand

There are 3 picklists. If particular values are selected in 1st and 2nd picklist the 3rd picklist must be updated.
I have Written the following rule condition:
**IIf(='BUILDING' AND ='RETAILS', 'BUIDLING', IIf(='BUILDING' AND ='RAILS','INFRA','INDUSTRY') )**

This Condition gives me Invalid Expession Syntax.

Comment: I don't know anything about CRM On Demand and don't know if it's relevant or not, but I'm pretty convinced you did not want `'BUIDLING'` there...

Answer (score 1):

A few things about CRMOD workflows:

1. A **workflow condition** are the specified conditions that must be met in order for the workflow to activate, if this is left blank it will activate everytime the trigger event(see below) happens e.g. If a record is created or modified.

a) Workflows are object specific e.g. Contact

b) The Trigger event inconjunction with the workflow condition above specifies when the workflow activates.

Once you have decided on your trigger then you have the option to select **actions**, this is where you would add the fields you want to update and specify the values.

You may find that you need more than one workflow depending on your business requirements.

I suggest you read the online user guide and oracle support resources to better understand the process before creating any automation in a product.

As for your If statement here is the syntax you need to follow:

IIf

The IIf function in Expression Builder returns one of two parameters based on the evaluation of a conditional expression. IIf is an abbreviation for Immediate If.

**Syntax**

IIf(expr, result_if_true, result_if_false)

**Alternate Syntax**

IIf(expr, expr_if_true, expr_if_false)

**Mixed Syntax**

IIf(expr, result_if_true, expr_if_false)
IIf(expr, expr_if_true, result_if_false)

**E.g.**

```
IIf([<PrimaryBillToState>]='OK' OR [<PrimaryBillToState>]='TX', 'Central', IIf([<PrimaryBillToState>]='CA', 'West', 'East'))
```

Kind Regards
Simon